# cannot get clients ip address in web.api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ip-address

I'm building a Web.Api (mvc & web.api) and try to get the clients ip adress with this code..

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Update([FromBody] BookInformation bookStatus)
{
  // Stuff...

  // Retrieve clients IP#
  var clientIp = (System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress
}
```

But I get this error:

> 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'Properties' and no extension method 'Properties' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

According to the exception message it is saying that `Request` is of type  `System.Web.HttpRequestBase` and `Properties` does not exist, which would be accurate for that class. This looks like you are mixing MVC and WebApi Controllers.

the `System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request` you are referencing is part of MVC `Controller.Request` but your method structure looks like it is suppose to be part of a Web Api `System.Web.Http.ApiController` which has a `System.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage Request` property as well.

Make sure you are inheriting from the correct controller.

```
public class BooksController : System.Web.Http.ApiController {...}
```

I've used this extension helper to get the client ip with an `ApiController`

```
static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions {
    private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
    private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";
    private const string OwinContext = "MS_OwinContext";

    public static string GetClientIpString(this HttpRequestMessage request) {
        //Web-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext)) {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
            if (ctx != null) {
                return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
            }
        }
        //Self-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage)) {
            dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
            if (remoteEndpoint != null) {
                return remoteEndpoint.Address;
            }
        }
        //Owin-hosting
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(OwinContext)) {
            dynamic ctx = request.Properties[OwinContext];
            if (ctx != null) {
                return ctx.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
            }
        }
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        // Always return all zeroes for any failure
        return "0.0.0.0";
    }
}
```

And used like this

```
public class BooksController : System.Web.Http.ApiController {

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Update([FromBody] BookInformation bookStatus) {
      // Stuff...

      // Retrieve clients IP#
      var clientIp = Request.GetClientIpString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to delete the lines under Owin-hosting that included references to System.Web.HttpContext because this was undefined for me. So had to delete these lines: 
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null) {
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
     }
But then it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should add reference
 System.ServiceModel
 and
 System.ServiceModel.channel